# postgresql: nested insert

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have two tables. Lets say tblA and tblB.
I need to insert a row in tblA and use the returned id as a value to be inserted as one of the columns in tblB.

I tried finding out this in documentation but could not get it. Well, is it possible to write a statement (intended to be used in prepared) like

```
INSERT INTO tblB VALUES 
(DEFAULT, (INSERT INTO tblA (DEFAULT, 'x') RETURNING id), 'y')
```

like we do for SELECT?

Or should I do this by creating a Stored Procedure?. I'm not sure if I can create a prepared statement out of a Stored Procedure.

Please advise.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two inserts, using `currval()` to retrieve the foreign key (provided that key is *serial*):

```
create temporary table tb1a (id serial primary key, t text);
create temporary table tb1b (id serial primary key,
                             tb1a_id int references tb1a(id),
                             t text);
begin;
insert into tb1a values (DEFAULT, 'x');
insert into tb1b values (DEFAULT, currval('tb1a_id_seq'), 'y');
commit;
```

The result:

```
select * from tb1a;
 id | t
----+---
  3 | x
(1 row)

select * from tb1b;
 id | tb1a_id | t
----+---------+---
  2 |       3 | y
(1 row)
```

Using currval in this way is safe whether in or outside of a transaction.  From the [Postgresql 8.4 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-sequence.html):

> currval
>
> Return the value most recently
>   obtained by nextval for this sequence
>   in the current session. (An error is
>   reported if nextval has never been
>   called for this sequence in this
>   session.) Because this is returning a
>   session-local value, it gives a
>   predictable answer whether or not
>   other sessions have executed nextval
>   since the current session did.

Comment: Maybe I am paranoid, *but* relying on `currval` is not the best idea. First, it assumes that the id is based on sequence. Second, unless explicitly using transactions the value of the key *may* change between the inserts, which screws up the integrity. Third, it is not reusable. But, that is only my opinion and you do not need to agree with it :)

Comment: @Sorrow, I've edited the answer to address your concern about the value of the key changing.  To the other charges, I plead *nolo contendere*.

Comment: @Waynce, your edit clarifies the issue. Therefore, my comment should now state "relying on `currval` is a good option provided that the id is tied to a sequence". The third concern, though, still holds - but it is a design issue not included in the question and may start an endless debate, so better stop it here.

Comment: @Sorrow, I agree, it's completely and utterly non-portable.  In any case, thanks for helping to make the answer better.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to wait for PostgreSQL 9.1 for this:

```
with
ids as (
insert ...
returning id
)
insert ...
from ids;
```

In the meanwhile, you need to use plpgsql, a temporary table, or some extra logic in your app...

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with 9.0 and the new `DO` for anonymous blocks:

```
do $$
declare 
  new_id integer;
begin
  insert into foo1 (id) values (default) returning id into new_id;
  insert into foo2 (id) values (new_id);
end$$;
```

This can be executed as a single statement. I haven't tried creating a PreparedStatement out of that though.

**Edit**

Another approach would be to simply do it in two steps, first run the insert into tableA using the returning clause, get the generated value through JDBC, then fire the second insert, something like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt_1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblA VALUES (DEFAULT, ?) returning id");
stmt_1.setString(1, "x");
stmt_1.execute(); // important! Do not use executeUpdate()!
ResultSet rs = stmt_1.getResult();
long newId = -1;
if (rs.next()) {
   newId = rs.getLong(1);
}
PreparedStatement stmt_2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblB VALUES (default,?,?)");
stmt_2.setLong(1, newId);
stmt_2.setString(2, "y");
stmt_2.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `AFTER INSERT` trigger for that. Something along the lines of:

```
create function dostuff() returns trigger as $$
begin
 insert into table_b(field_1, field_2) values ('foo', NEW.id);
 return new; --values returned by after triggers are ignored, anyway
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

create trigger trdostuff after insert on table_name for each row execute procedure dostuff();
```

`after insert` is needed because you need to have the id to reference it. Hope this helps.

**Edit**

A trigger will be called in the same "block" as the command that triggered it, even if not using transactions - in other words, it becomes somewhat *part* of that command.. Therefore, there is no risk of something changing the referenced id between inserts.